# Run the.WAR on my Ubuntu Server?

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, servlets, genexus

I have a kb "Tienda" created with (Java environment) and MySQL. I have created the `Tienda.WAR` and upload it manually to my Ubuntu Server and deployed it/unzipped (the 4 folders "META-INF", "static", "WEB-INF" & "Metadata").

I copied the "unzipped" folder (Tienda) and I had thus:
`var/www/Tienda`

In other sites put there to do it in `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/Tienda`. I have put it in both directories. Now, since there isn't an "index.html" I do not know how to access my 'home' created in GeneXus.

I tried to open, `localhost:8080/Tienda/servlet/com.AppTienda.home` resulting in: `State HTTP 404 - /Tienda/servlet/com.AppTienda.home`

But the servlet server is installed properly; if I open `localhost:8080` I get the "It's Working" page.

How can I solve this?

And another question, what do you do if a client tells them that you want to install the application on your company servers?

Comment: Make sure you have installed Java and Apache Tomcat, also you have configured base path for both. One more thing there is no need to unzip .war file.

Comment: Hi,
If that is the apache package, because as mentioned, if I write localhost:8080 get me the web "It's Wotk!"
Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete the app directory, put your .war file in the webapps directory and let Tomcat unzip it automatically, that way permissions are set by Tomcat and not by your user account.
2. Check your Tomcat logs, if there's any problem in the deployment you will see it there.

Comment: Hi,
 I'll try to do what I said,  what I don't know is like watching the Tomcat. logs

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: And as I have to put the address in firefox so read me the 'home' GeneXus created?( localhost: 8080/Tienda/servlet/com.AppTienda.home)???

Comment: Tomcat logs are usually located at: `/usr/share/tomcat7/logs/` or `/var/log/tomcat7/`, you should check `catalina.out` and `localhost` logs. Keep in mind that Tomcat is case sensitive, your package name shouldn't have uppercase letters, the case must match exactly the war name and the package name.